# How to delete pipeline execution records on SageMaker Studio?

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I want to delete pipeline execution records appearing on **SageMaker Studio** to keep order and remove unnecessary records. I am fine with doing it via python, but i also accept any other tool available.

I know the possibility of deleting the entire pipeline or the individual experiments generated for each step in it with [delete_pipeline()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.delete_pipeline) rather than [delete_experiment()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.delete_experiment). However, this does not solve the problem. In the list of [**boto3 APIs**](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html) I could not find any "delete_execution" (instead there is [update_pipeline_execution()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.update_pipeline_execution) but does not seem to allow deletion).

For example, in this image, I would like to eliminate the failed execution, without deleting the entire pipeline:

[image: SageMaker pipeline executions]

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to delete individual pipeline executions; it is an immutable history of executions, in the same way that Step Functions execution history cannot be deleted.

Comment: If I delete the pipeline, all executions are also deleted (at least in graphical terms on sagemaker studio). And if I then recreate the pipeline with the same name (it probably has a unique id somewhere), the previous executions don't reappear (so it's like losing track of them). Is the only solution to go this round and lose all the executions each time?

Comment: If your goal is to get rid of the execution history, yes you can do that. I'd question the motivation though; finished executions have no impact on billing and are filterable/sortable, so it's a purely aesthetic concern at that point

Comment: That's right, the objective is purely aesthetic. However, I don't want to delete the entire history. Suppose we launched a completely wrong execution, we would not want to keep track of it because it could create ambiguity in the list. There might tend to be a couple of executions completely out of context and it would be difficult to distinguish them at a glance from the good ones.